# What does compile with -DPSAPI_VERSION=1 mean?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, compilation

In the link below the C++ code's comments it says;

```
// and compile with -DPSAPI_VERSION=1
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/psapi/nf-psapi-enumprocessmodules

How do we compile with -DPSAPI_VERSION=1 ?

Comment: It means to compile all the relevant source files as if there is a `#define PSAPI_VERSION 1` at the top (or, at least, before the first time the macro `PSAPI_VERSION` is used or tested).   Short of editing files to add that macro definition (e.g. in a user-written header file that is included by all source files) this can be achieved with most command line compilers by adding `-DPSAPI_VERSION=1` to the command line when compiling those files, or in IDEs through project settings (the specifics of the latter varies with IDE).

Answer (score 0):

Two possibilities

just before the include of windows.h add

```
#define PSAPI_VERSION=1
```

or in the project properties there is a place to define macros, add `PSAPI_VERSION=1` there

Answer (score 0):

Macros are defined in the program. I usually define a macro in the cmake file as a switch. Then in the program, if the macro is found to be defined, the algorithm library call is executed, because my algorithm library is sometimes not configured properly.

```
CMakeLists.txt

add_definitions(-DRecognitionLIB")

in cpp file
#ifdef RecognitionLib
#include <GBProcess.h>
#include <AIScrapperVision.h>
#endif

function aaa()
{
#ifdef RecognitionLib
  some code
#endif
}
```